# Highlight lines longer than 80 characters in Vim doesn't work with php

Tags: vim, coding-style, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to identify lines longer than 80 characters with Vim and I've found this solution:

```
match ErrorMsg '\%80v.\+'
```

This works in an html file or in the .vimrc file, but not in php files. I also tried this directly in a php file and it didn't work either

```
/\%>80v.\+
```

Any suggestion to identify the problem?

Comment: I cannot understand why your `/` search has something to do with filetype. are you sure your php file has lines longer than 80c? also did you try just rename your working html to php and test again? are there special settings for your php filetype, overwriting the search highlighting?

Comment: somehow I solved the problem. Probably I have some plugin conflicting with this, but I'm still not sure which one

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `:match` (and the related `:2match`, `:3match`) is that there can be only one pattern; following commands clear the previous one. (That's why the `matchadd()` function was introduced.)

You can check whether your definition (it has `'id': 1`) is still active with

```
:echo getmatches()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more flexible solution to highlight just the characters beyond 80 chars using a toggleable function. Replace the first line with whatever keybind you prefer.

```
nnoremap <leader>h :call ToggleOverLengthHighlight()<CR>
let g:overlength_enabled = 0
highlight OverLength ctermbg=black guibg=#212121

function! ToggleOverLengthHighlight()
    if g:overlength_enabled == 0
        match OverLength /\%79v.*/
        let g:overlength_enabled = 1
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned on'
    else
        match
        let g:overlength_enabled = 0
        echo 'OverLength highlighting turned off'
    endif
endfunction
```